# How to change docker default storage size

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I've been having loads of issues with `kubectl` not having enough space. How can I increase the default storage size allocated to `docker`?

None of minikube recommendations worked.

```
1. Run "docker system prune" to remove unused Docker data (optionally with "-a")
2. Increase the storage allocated to Docker for Desktop by clicking on:
   Docker icon > Preferences > Resources > Disk Image Size
3. Run "minikube ssh -- docker system prune" if using the Docker container runtime
```

And the second is not possible from command line...

Comment: Can you elaborate how any of this is related to `kubectl` ?

Comment: I get `ImagePullBackOff` when I try to deploy nginx on the cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your comment into consideration

> I get ImagePullBackOff when I try to deploy nginx on the cluster –
> Caterina

You can specify minikube's disk allocations separately:

`minikube start --memory=8192 --cpus=4 --disk-size=50g`

Which can help you to work around the disk space issues as the default is significantly smaller:  `--disk-size string Disk size allocated to the minikube VM (format: <number>[<unit>], where unit = b, k, m or g). (default "20000mb")`

Comment: I'm on Linux, spefically Ubuntu, not MacOS, and yes I'm already giving 14Gb to minikube. I ran `minikube config set disk-size 14000` prior to starting the cluster.

Comment: That is less than the default

Comment: Which one is the default? Why does it take so much space? My VM is only 32 Gb

Comment: >      --disk-size string                  Disk size allocated to the minikube VM (format: <number>[<unit>], where unit = b, k, m or g). (default "20000mb") [https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/start/](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/start/)

Comment: Thanks Rich I changed my VM disk space to 100 Gb and I didn't get the error message again. But could you please let me know what is taking so much disk-space? I just instantiated 3 nodes and deployed nginx on them.

Comment: if you do `minikube ssh` you can look around like on a regular box to see what's using a lot. eg `docker image ls` and `docker ps -a`